# Why Google chrome return message as undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```js
var a, b, c;
alert (typeof a);
a = 50;
alert (typeof a);
b = 30;
c = a+b;
console.log(c);
```

[image]

I was doing small play with javascript code with google chrome inspect element. And found one issue, all time after declaring variable chrome returning message as undefined.

Can any one help me to understand why it's showing message as undefined?

Comment: Show your code please. A screen shot of your console is not helpful.

Comment: It prints undefined because that's the return value of the statement. `alert` and `console.log` return nothing, they are `void`, hence their return result is `undefined`.

Comment: Hi Mjh I can understand for first alert it will show undefined (because I just declare only variable), but for next alert and console.log it should not. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `alert` and `console.log` are always void functions, so it will always display `undefined` any time you invoke them in the console.

Comment: I wonder why this question was marked down. its a genuine question for a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome's console shows return value as `undefined` for everything that doesn't return any value in addition to expressions that actually evaluate into `undefined`. That means, that it will show `undefined` for statements that simply cannot return anything because it's not allowed by language specification, like variable and function declarations.

So, no you're not doing anything wrong, it's just the way how console works.